# Disable context menu in compiled Flash projector application

Tags: settings, command-line-arguments, flash

I would like to disable the context menu of a Flash projector application. Unfortunately it's an older project and the source code is not available anyone. Therefore I'd like to know if there's e.g. a commandline parameter I could use to prohibit its use. Or are there any other I options I have? Basically I don't want the user to zoom, print or edit Flash player settings.

Answer (score 0):

Load old swf in another swf and disable context menu in new swf.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a exe (Flash projector) not a swf file.